# Web application to android app

Tags: javascript, android, mysql

So, I have this web app to book some reservation, which connect to mysql database using javascript and the UI layout is using html and css

Is it possible to convert the whole thing into android app, while changing the layout from html to xml like in android studio? I want to change the layout (buttons etc ) and make it editable in android studio

And if that's not possible and I have to make it from scratch, can I use those javascript to connect to the same db while using android studio, so I only need to create the UI?

Comment: You could look into PhoneGap since you already have a working app written in js.

Answer (score 0):

Create a **PhoneGap** project. i think so [Phonegap](http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-phonegap-android-studio/)

Answer (score 0):

> **Option 1** :
>
> **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)** is the most popular a free and open-source HTML, CSS,  free ans open-source JavaScript framework for developing
>   responsive, mobile-first web sites.
>
> It contains HTML- and CSS-based design templates for typography,
>   forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as
>   optional JavaScript extensions. It aims to ease the development of
>   dynamic websites and web applications.
>
> It looks like you can try Bootstrap on your site to make it Responsive
>   in mobile. [Best Practices for Web Apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/best-practices.html)
>
> **Option 2**:
>
> [**Apache Cordova**](https://cordova.apache.org/)(formerly PhoneGap) is a popular mobile
>   application development framework originally created by Nitobi. Adobe
>   Systems purchased Nitobi in 2011, rebranded it as PhoneGap, and later
>   released an open source version of the software called Apache Cordova.
>
> Apache Cordova enables software programmers to build applications
>   for mobile devices using JavaScript, HTML5, and CSS3, instead of
>   relying on platform-specific APIs like those in Android, iOS, or
>   Windows Phone

If you are starting from the scratch,The controller side will be done in pure Android, definitely not in Javascript

Please read [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You could make it as hybrid app. Just convert your html , JavaScript and CSS3 into the android app and IOS. there are few technology to build hybrid app
- phonegap http://phonegap.com/
- cordova 
- ionic